# WordPress incorrectly redirects to local IP address?

Tags: server, apache, linux

I have my wordpress server set up using php, mysql, and apache on my raspberry pi. I also have a dynamic dns hostname and configured my router's port forwardiing settings.

When trying to access my server from outside of my local LAN, when I type in my dynamic dns host, (for example, my phone on 4G mobile network or at school), the site incorrectly redirects to the server's local IP address: 192.168.0.18 so the page fails to load up.

This is very weird because I also have owncloud set up on my pi and in the same condition I try to access mydynamicdnshost/owncloud, it doesn't redirect me to local IP and the page loads up successfully.

I know this is a really basic problem with wordpress configuration but I simply cannot fix it. So does anyone know that please answer my question. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Site URL in Options Table.

```
UPDATE  `wp_options` SET  `option_value` =  'YOUR_SITE_URL' WHERE  `option_name` = 'siteurl' OR  `option_name` = 'home';
```

Also change the static URLs in your post content.

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_content` = REPLACE(post_content, '192.168.0.18/YOUR_LOCAL_SITE_URL/', 'YOUR_SITE_URL/');
```

Don't forget to change the table prefix if its not 'wp_'.

---

**Edit :** Access PHPMyAdmin of your server. Contact your Hosting Provider if you are not aware of this.

Select your WordPress Database & Access wp_options table. And change 'siteurl' && 'home' attribute values to your Live Website URL.

Hire a developer if you are not sure what you are doing !

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, could you please tell me which file contains those configurations? I'm a completely newbie to this field. I tried to find them in wp-config.php, etc but none of them were found.

Comment: These settings are exposed on the Settings / General page too, as **WordPress Address (URL)** and **Site Address (URL)**. [This Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) provides more information. But I'm not sure that the answer will work; I'd think that you need to update these settings to the dynamic hostname you're using, not to the local address.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: @GaborBarat 
Agree, That the approach given i [this codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)  is better than my solution. But if its not done properly it will change the site and home url in options table on each and every request.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired @jitendra-rana answer, the direction was correct, but not full.

1. Do dump of your database to the file.
2. Open dump file and replace all `http://192.168.0.18` to `http://your_site`
3. Execute dump file to replace all data in database.
4. Clear cache (hard reload) of your site.

Profit.